# Gawk: Insert line using lookup data from another file

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I'm trying to insert lines into a file, where the data being inserted is based on data stored in another file.  I've tried this in both Sed and Awk, but can't figure out in either how to access the second file.  This is probably a stretch for Sed, perhaps less so for Awk?

The main file:

```
# alpha --
some data
some more data

# beta --
some data
some more data

# gamma --
some data
some more data
```

The lookup file:

```
alpha    This is a description of alpha
gamma    This guys description
delta    And a third description
```

The result should look like this:

```
# alpha --
Description = This is a description of alpha
some data
some more data

# beta --
some data
some more data

# gamma --
Description = This guys description
some data
some more data
```

Notice that the lookup file may not have a description for the item, and that's ok; the "Description = " line will just be omitted.

I figured this much out in Awk, but don't know how to reference the lookup file:

```
awk '{
    if ($0 ~ /^# [^ ]* --/) {
        print $0;
        print "Description = ";   # How to lookup $2's description??
    } else {
        print $0;
    }
}' <file1.txt
```

How can I obtain the description from the second file using Awk?  Or is there a better tool for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {k=$1; sub(/^\S+\s+/,"Description = "); dict[k]=$0; next} 
               1; 
       /^#/    {if($2 in dict) print dict[$2]}' dict file
```

Comment: Thank you!  This totally works, but what does the second line (`1;`) do?  I can't find that in the documentation anyware.

Comment: it's a true condition, ends up invoking the default statement which is `print`.  So `1;` is equivalent to `{print}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, supplying both files on the `awk` command line in the logical order (descriptions first, so it can read and store them, followed by the data that needs them inserted):

```
$ awk '(NR == FNR) { 
    desc[$1]=$2; 
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
      desc[$1]=desc[$1]" "$i 
    }; 
  }  
  (NR > FNR) { 
    print; 
    if (/^#/) { 
      print "Description = "desc[$2]; 
    }  
  }' desc.txt main.txt
```

Which produces this output given your sample file contents:

```
# alpha --
Description = This is a description of alpha
some data
some more data

# beta --
Description =
some data
some more data

# gamma --
Description = This guys description
some data
some more data
```

Explanation:

The awk variable `NR` contains the  **N**umber of **R**ecords seen so far.  Normally, a record is a line - although you can change the record separator - so this is effectively the current line number, counted continuously across all the files being processed. In this case its value will run from 1 to 14.

The variable `FNR` (**F**ile **N**umber of **R**ecords) works the same way, but resets to 1 at the start of each new file. So in this case its value will run from 1 to 4 and then 1 to 10.

By comparing these two values, the program can determine which file is currently being processed. If `NR` and `FNR` are the same, we know we're in the first file, and use the contents of the line to populate the associative array `desc`. The first field (`$1`) is the key; we concatenate the rest of the fields together to form the value.

If `NR` is *not* equal to `FNR` (it can only be greater, never less), we know we're in the second file. In that case, we first print the line (which we always do, so we just make it unconditional instead of repeating the statement). Then we check to see if we need to append the description. If we do, look it up in the `desc` array - using `$2` (the second whitespace-separated field on the line, the first being the "#") as the lookup key.

Comment: I think no need of `(NR > FNR)`, just after your loop while reading first file, you can just put `next`

Comment: No, that loop needs to run on every line of the first file and not on the second. It's looping over the fields of each line; how could it be looping over the lines? How does `next` help?

Comment: I mean after `(NR == FNR) { 
    desc[$1]=$2; 
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
      desc[$1]=desc[$1]" "$i 
    } next }`

Comment: `NR == FNR` will be true only when `awk` reads first file, so `(NR > FNR)` is not required, `next` statement is for stop processing current line, its like `continue` statement, so it will go to next line, and `NR` will be always greater than `FNR` when `awk` reads second file

Comment: But that loop needs to run on EVERY line of the first file. If I call `next there, I'll only get one description in the array!

Comment: ultimately you can simplify like this : `awk 'NR == FNR{  
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
      desc[$1]=$1 in desc ? desc[$1]" "$i : $i ; 
    next
  }  
  { 
    print; 
    if (/^#/) { 
      print "Description = "desc[$2]; 
    }  
  }' desc.txt main.txt`

Comment: I don't see how that's any improvement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134710/discussion-between-akshay-hegde-and-mark-reed).

Comment: No need. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the excellent explanation.  I ended up trying @karakfa's solution first because it was shorter (less stuff for me to digest) and it worked, even though I didn't understand it all.  Your answer was very helpful in teaching me about Awk, though.